# Index and sort on nested variable field MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document that looks like this :

```
{
  "_id": "chatID"
  "presence": {
    "userID1": 1647627240464,
    "userID2": 1647227540464
  },
}
```

I need to query for each `userID` the chats where he is `present` and order by the timestamp in the `presence` map.

I am aware that this is probably not the best way to do, before i had 1 element per user meaning duplicating the `chatID`s, but it's a pain to update them all because it would look like :

```
{
    "_id": "userID1chatID",
    "at": 1647627240464,
    "ids": "30EYwO01_Nyq7dMqe_O3vfL3AH",
    "members": ["userID1", "userID2", "userID3"],
    "owner": "userID1",
    "present": true,
    "uid": "chatID",
    "url": "databaseURL"
}
```

This would allow me to `find` the chats where `userID1` is `present: true` and order by `at` `DESCENDING`.
The problem with this is that i need to update the `at` attribute for all the documents (one per user) for this same chat room.

How can i do this same query while maintaining a single document with `present` as a `map` ?

Problem : the index would be on a variable : `userID1`, `userID2`, etc...
like : `present.userID1` and seems to not be convenient for use when `userID1` can be removed from the `present` map if the user leaves the chat.

Please let me know if this is unclear, thanks in advance.